# How to replace all _ with spaces in all directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I just wanted to know how to replace all '_' with spaces in all of my directories.

I found this command, and it worked to change all spaces with '_', but if I want to do the opposite, how can I do ahahhaha?

```
for f in *\ *; do mv "$f" "${f// /_}"; done
```

This command doesn't work:

```
for f in *\ *; do mv "$f" "${f/_// }"; done
```

And,
I made 50 folders based on 50 images. So all my folders finish with `.png`, do you know how to remove it from the names too?

Comment: You found howto rename the files somewhere surely there are more examples where it came from but to answer your question replace the `*\ *` with just `*`, also always put an `echo` before any commands just so you know what is going to happen, e.g. `echo mv ..` and not just blindly running an arbitrary commands that you don't know whats going to happen.

Comment: I think the problem is in the {} no? And do you know for the other question?

Comment: see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030 for you questions.

Comment: $ for f in *\ *; do mv -- "$f" "${f/_// }"; done
mv: cannot stat '* *': No such file or directory
Hey thanks! I succed with the .png question, but with the replace underscore with spaces it doesnt work. Do you know why friend? :O Thanks!

Comment: and if I change `*\ *` with just `*` it says: mv: cannot move 'My_Title_Here' to 'My/ Title_Here': No such file or directory